# std::weak_ptr.lock semantic in multi-threaded c++

Tags: c++, weak-ptr

std says:

```
shared_ptr<T> lock() const noexcept;
```

Returns:

```
expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this).
```

but in between expired returning false (the object still exists) and the construction of the shared_ptr another thread could remove the last strong reference, thus throwing an
unexpected exception? how to prevent this?

or do i miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to prevent it, it is taken care of by the implementation of the standard library.

The cited code is for illustration purposes only: the behavior of `lock()` is as this code, but atomically with regard to other threads.

If you want to know how it is done, you can peek the source code. It is a template class, so the code will surely be in the header files. But beware! The standard C++ library source code is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: "the behavior of lock() is as this code, but atomically with regard to other threads." If so, the standard text says nothing, and thus is defective.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: The standard doesn't define the implementation, but the *value* of the result. So the standard text is fine.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: On second thought, I recall the atomicity of `weak_ptr::lock()` from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm), but now I'm not sure if this applies to the libstd implementation. [This](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/shared_ptr.html) and  maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9ceah3b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) seem to suggest that they do, but I now cannot find confirmation in the standard...